# How to tell if a command is a function call, a script call, a builtin command, or an external program?

Tags: bash

In Bash, we can run a function call, a script call, a builtin command, or an external program as a command.

Conversely, how can we tell if a given command name is a function call, a script call, a builtin command, or an external program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `type` built-in can tell you whether a command is a built-in, function or an external program:

```
> type locate
locate is /usr/bin/locate
> type type
type is a shell builtin
```

`type -t` provides easier to parse output.

`type` doesn't distinguish between compiled executables and scripts; however, you could use `file` to distinguish between those two anytime `type` reports that a given name is an external command:

```
> file ~/bin/c
/Users/steved/bin/c: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text
> file /usr/bin/locate
/usr/bin/locate: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```